# How to prevent my to-do list from reloading page after adding item?

Tags: javascript

`

```js
  const itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

  document.querySelector("#enter").addEventListener("click", () => {
      const item = document.querySelector("#item")
      createItem(item)
  })

  document.querySelector("#item").addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  if(e.key === "Enter"){
      const item = document.querySelector("#item")
      createItem(item)

  }

  })

  function displayDate(){
      let date = new Date()
      date = date.toString().split(" ")
      date = date[1] + " " + date[2] + " " + date[3]
      document.querySelector("#date").innerHTML = date
  }

  function displayItems(){
      let items = ""
      for(let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++){
        items += `<div class="item">
                    <div class="input-controller">
                      <textarea disabled>${itemsArray[i]}</textarea>
                      <div class="edit-controller">
                      <span class="material-symbols-outlined deleteBtn">
                      delete
                      </span>
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined editBtn">edit</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="update-controller">
                      <button class="saveBtn">Save</button>
                      <button class="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>`
      }
      document.querySelector(".to-do-list").innerHTML = items
      activateDeleteListeners()
      activateEditListeners()
      activateSaveListeners()
      activateCancelListeners()

    }

    function activateDeleteListeners(){
      let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteBtn")
      deleteBtn.forEach((dB, i) => {
        dB.addEventListener("click", () => { deleteItem(i) })
      })
    }

    function activateEditListeners(){
      const editBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".editBtn")
      const updateController = document.querySelectorAll(".update-controller")
      const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input-controller textarea")
      editBtn.forEach((eB, i) => {
        eB.addEventListener("click", () => { 
          updateController[i].style.display = "block"
          inputs[i].disabled = false })
      })
    }

    function activateSaveListeners(){
      const saveBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".saveBtn")
      const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input-controller textarea")
      saveBtn.forEach((sB, i) => {
        sB.addEventListener("click", () => {
          updateItem(inputs[i].value, i)
        })
      })
    }

    function activateCancelListeners(){
      const cancelBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".cancelBtn")
      const updateController = document.querySelectorAll(".update-controller")
      const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input-controller textarea")
      cancelBtn.forEach((cB, i) => {
        cB.addEventListener("click", () => {
          updateController[i].style.display = "none"
          inputs[i].disabled = true
          inputs[i].style.border = "none"
        })
      })
    }

    function createItem(item){
      itemsArray.push(item.value)
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))

      location.reload()
    }

    function deleteItem(i){
      itemsArray.splice(i,1)
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
      location.reload()
    }

    function updateItem(text, i){
      itemsArray[i] = text
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
      location.reload()
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      displayDate()
      displayItems()
    };
```

```css
body {
        background-image: url('death-note-gif.gif');
        /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
        background-attachment: fixed;
       /* background-size: cover;*/
        }

    
.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 400,
  'GRAD' 0,
  'opsz' 48
}
```

```html
<main class="app">
    <div class="header-title">
    <h1>Death Note: To-Do List</h1>
    <h2>What task are we killing today?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class ="input-header">
        <h1><span id="date"></span></h1>
        <div class="to-do-input">
            <input type="text" id="item" placeholder="Choose..."><button id="enter">Write</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="to-do-list"></div>
</main>
```

`The To-Do List works great, except for the page reloading every time I add something to the list. After it reloads, the item/s still show but I don't want a page reload to activate.  I know I am supposed to add a prevent default but when I add it and remove the 'location.reload()' it gives me an error.

Comment: Is there a form? I don't see one, but the behavior suggests there is. By default, buttons are `type=submit`; set them to type=`button` and they wont' try to submit.

Comment: `it gives me an error.`: what's the error? Wondering if you need to pass the event to the event listeners and *then* call `event.preventDefault();` Otherwise it doesn't know *what* default to prevent.

Comment: My bad there's no error when I remove location.reload() and I added type = "submit" to the button in the HTML and it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I've edited your two snippets to be together as one snippet so the HTML and JS can run together

Comment: type=submit will definitely submit the form. But as the answer below states, location.reload() will definitely reload. What's the purpose of that call if you don't want to reload?

Comment: I suppose i thought it would add the tasks, which is does, and it does successfully and when i remove the location.reload() it doesn't add tasks anymore

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with the following:

- HTML
- The error message that you get when including the `preventDefault()` function

Your issue is caused by the line `location.reload()` The event listeners should include `preventDefault()`.

*Update*

`displayItems()` is only called on window load. So your `createItem()` updates the `itemsArray` correctly, but does not update the DOM.

Just add `displayItems()` to `createItems()` and you're good to go.

Comment: That worked thank you! How do i apply that same logic to delete and edit?

Comment: Just replace `location.reload` with `displayItems()` in both `deleteItem()` and `updateItem()`